# error: no suitable user-defined conversion from "Data" to "std::__cxx11::string" exists when using icc 17.0

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, icc

I am getting a compiler error when I am trying to compile with specific compiler version.
ie. icc 17.0 with `-std=c++17 -O3`

**Compiler Error:**

```
source>(19): error: no suitable user-defined conversion from "Data" to "std::__cxx11::string" exists
      Data temp{std::forward<Data>(d)};
                ^

compilation aborted for <source> (code 2)
ASM generation compiler returned: 2
<source>(19): error: no suitable user-defined conversion from "Data" to "std::__cxx11::string" exists
      Data temp{std::forward<Data>(d)};
                ^

compilation aborted for <source> (code 2)
Execution build compiler returned: 2
```

**Code:**

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Data {
  std::string id{};
  std::string rowData{};
  int totalRawDataLength{};

  std::vector<int> rawDataOffset{};
  std::vector<int> rawDataLength{};

  Data() = default;
  Data(const Data&d) =default;
  Data(Data &&d) =default;
};

Data ProcessData(Data &&d) {
    Data temp{std::forward<Data>(d)};
    // some code
    return temp;
}

int main() {
  Data d{};
  d.id = "id_001";
  d.rowData = "some data";
  d.rawDataOffset.emplace_back(4);
  d.rawDataLength.emplace_back(4);
  auto x = ProcessData(std::move(d));
  std::cout << "Test:" << x.id << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b7rjWz)

following code works for all version of `gcc` and it works with the higher version of icc with same compiler options.
it even works for `-std=c++11 -O3` for icc 17.0

on further debugging found out that something is wrong with default copy constructor which is being generated.

[Code with copyconstructor](https://godbolt.org/z/Kz4xzd)

I am not able to understand what's wrong happening here, is it some kind of compiler bug which got resolved in later releases?

Comment: What happens if you add [`#include <utility>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) to your list of headers?

Comment: @dfrib nope I am not trying link libs compiled for different ABI

Comment: @AdrianMole getting the same error

Comment: This seems like it is applying aggregate initialization, rather than calling a constructor. You could try `Data temp(std::forward<Data>(d));` (using parentheses instead of curly brackets) and/or replacing the default constructor with `Data() { }` to work around the problem.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm your suggestion solves the compilation issue even replacing default copy constructor with `Data(const Data&d) {}` solves the compilation issue. can you help me understand what's going wrong and why that's not the issue in other  version or different c++ standard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is yet another curious example of when [the fickle aggregate](https://dfrib.github.io/the-fickle-aggregate/) strikes, here alongside an arguable bug in the ICC compiler (version 17.0).

---

#### `Data` is an aggregate class in C++14 and C++17 (but not in C++11)

In C++11, an aggregate class was defined as, as per [[dcl.init.aggr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init.aggr#1) ([N3337](https://dfrib.github.io/the-fickle-aggregate/)) [**emphasis** mine]:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause [class]) **with no user-provided constructors** ([class.ctor]), **no brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members** ([class.mem]), **no private or protected non-static data members** (Clause [class.access]), no base classes (Clause [class.derived]), and no virtual functions ([class.virtual]).

In C++14 and C++17, except for some `explicit` details in the latter, the rules are mostly the same as in C++11, except that the requirement

> [...] **no brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members**

has been removed.

Thus, as your class `Data` have no *user-provided* constructors (see [[dcl.fct.def.default]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.fct.def.default#4)) and moreover only public data members, it is an aggregate in C++14 and C++17, whereas, due to its default member initializers, it is not an aggregate in C++11.

---

#### ICC wrongly applies aggregate initalization for C++14 and C++17, where `Data` is an aggregate

Now, the follow direct-braced-init initialization

> ```
> Data temp{std::forward<Data>(d)}
> ```

will enumerate constructor overloads in C++11, whereas in C++14 and C++17 it is direct initialization, particularly by the following rule (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

> The effects of list initialization of an object of type T are:
>
> - If T is an aggregate class **and the initializer list has a single element of the same or derived type** (possibly cv-qualified), the
>   object is initialized from that element (by copy-initialization for
>   copy-list-initialization, or by direct-initialization for
>   direct-list-initialization).

If the conditions of the bullet above does not apply, direct-brace-init for an aggregate class will be aggregate initialization. This *should not happen here*, but ICC seemingly wrongly apply aggregate initialization in C++14 and C++17 (where `Data` is an aggregate class), using `std::forward<Data>(d)` to direct-initialize the first data member of `Data` (namely the data member `id` which is of type `std::string`) rather than direct-initialization of `Data` itself; all the other data members are initialized by their associated default member initializers.

---

#### Replacing an explicitly-defaulted constructor with a user-provided one make an aggregate class become a non-aggregate class

> [...] on further debugging found out that something is wrong with default copy constructor which is being generated.

In the example you show here you have simply *provided* your own copy-constructor, as compared to explicitly-defaulting it at its first declaration. This means the class `Data` is no longer an aggregate (in any of C++11 through C++17).

---

#### C++20 sorts out most of the earlier aggregate confusion

Note that as per C++20 most of the aggregate confusion has been resolved, as per the implementation of [P1008R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1008r1.pdf) (*Prohibit aggregates with user-declared constructors*), specifically by no longer allowing aggregates to have user-*declared* constructors, a stricter requirement for a class to be an aggregate than just prohibiting *user-provided* constructors.

Comment: make sense Thanks mate!